# How to store video/audio/big text within protege?

Tags: ontology, protege

I created an ontology and in the phase of inserting individuals and storing values I face many problems.

I try to store a video/audio file and big text into ontology using protege, but I don't know how to store video/audio file and big text into database.

For example, when I searched in protege, I cannot find any data type for  a video/audio file. I just found 'string' data type for an individual and when I choose it I cannot store a big text in the individuals.

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Binary data can be stored as BASE64 encoded literal. However, storing the actual video data as part of the ontology is not what most APIs for OWL are designed for (there is little advantage in having this data as part of the ontology, since there is no extra inference that can be extracted from the binary data, in OWL).

I would suggest storing the file path or whichever identifier for the video is appropriate, and store the video in a way that's designed to cope with large binary files.